# Solr: how add language attribute to solr documents and search by it?

Tags: java, solr, tokenize

In solr are adding documents on several languages, in tokenizer I add codes to words and can search by code in several languages. But now if I search word "media" (not by code) I've get it in several languages, how can I specify language in query?(maybe I will have add attributes to documents)

Comment: What does your schema look like for those fields?

Comment: <field name="content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />

Comment: I can add attributes of language to each token and search with "and content:ENG", but highlighting highlihgt all words in sentence then.